# Resize Google Maps when printing

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So im using this function to print my Google Maps API V3:

```
function printit(){
var content = window.document.getElementById("map-canvas");
var newWindow = window.open(); // open a new window
newWindow.document.write(content.innerHTML); // write the map into the new window
newWindow.print(); // print the new window
};
```

And this is the HTML button that im using:

```
<button onClick="printit()">Print</button>
```

The problem is that map-canvas is set to 100% width with CSS, so wen the map is printed only left side is visible (as much as it fits on A4 paper). I tryed adding this:

```
document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.width = "900px";
```

But i get an error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @NoamHacker its written: undefined. This is in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was not as simple as i thought it would be, here is the complete working code, it was tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and it works perfectly:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function printit(){
  var newWidth = 700,
    content = document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style")[0],
    translateX = (content.clientWidth - newWidth) / 2,
    orgTranslate = content.firstChild.firstChild.style.transform,
    left = content.firstChild.firstChild.style.left;

  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write(content.outerHTML);
  var c = win.document.getElementsByClassName("gm-style")[0];
  c.style.width = newWidth + "px";

    if (orgTranslate) {
    orgTranslate = orgTranslate.split(",");
    orgTranslate[4]-= translateX;
    c.firstChild.firstChild.style.transform = orgTranslate.join(",");
  } else {
    c.firstChild.firstChild.style.left = (parseInt(left, 10) - translateX) + "px"; // firefox uses absolute positioning
  }

  win.print();
};

var center;
function calculateCenter() {
  center = map.getCenter();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  calculateCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.setCenter(center);
});
</script>
```

And also the print button:

```
<button onClick="printit()">Print</button>
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API normally uses the ID `map_canvas` for the height and width properties instead of `map-canvas`. So it has to be:

```
document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.width = "900px";
```

Comment: Thx for youre answer. Could you please edit youre answer so i know exactly where in function printit() i have to put this line of code?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Something wierd is happening wen i use this code. it still dosent print the midle of the map, it prints left side, but after iclose print window in chrome then map on my website changes width. if you have any time you can check this out here: http://www.auto-karta-hrvatske.com/

Comment: [This page](http://imgur.com/TflSdSY) seems to be working fine. I can't see the problem you're talking about. Can you please post a screenshot to clarify, or further explain it?

Comment: This page you posted is ok, but i wanted to use this simple scrypt to print all other pages too. Check the homepage from link i posted, under map on the left side i put small button with youre code. Wen you use it only left side of the map is printed not the center. Here is example, i centered italy in the midlle of the map, and wen i click print i get this: http://prntscr.com/bj3jbx

Comment: Alright, I updated my code and also included a function to center the map on a resize. See if this works for you.

Comment: Now the map resizing is working, but it does not center the map, i tryed few diferent centering functions and nothing, here is the code i used on homepage: http://prntscr.com/bj543v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115213/discussion-between-everthing-and-dreadlord).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```